# Enable Azure cosmos gremlin request logging in application insight

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have azure app service. Requests against other Azure services are traced (appear as 'dependencies') in AppInsights. Requests against the Gremlin API are not appearing in AppInsights though, how to achieve it?

Comment: About cosmos db, only tracked automatically if HTTP/HTTPS is used. TCP mode won't be captured by Application Insights. So if you need to manually tracking dependencies, by TelemetryClient. Here's a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#manually-tracking-dependencies) on it.

Answer (score 2):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) described

> 1. "Application Insights" is **aimed at** the development team, to help you understand how your **application** is performing and how
>    it's being used.
> 2. Azure Cosmos DB is tracked automatically only if HTTP/HTTPS is used. TCP mode won't be captured by Application Insights.

If you want it to show some information about other service like cosmos db, you might call it through http request or configure your app with that service manually, refer to this doc: [Manually tracking dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#manually-tracking-dependencies).